# MySQL access string like an array

Tags: mysql, arrays, stored-procedures

I'm was trying to make function that will return random character. What I have is a string that contains alphanumerics. In Postgresql I can set text as array, but I don't know how MySQL do same. for example:

in postgresql

```
DECLARE chars TEXT[] := '{0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I,J,K,L,M,N,O,P,Q,R,S,T,U,V,W,X,Y,Z,a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j,k,l,m,n,o,p,q,r,s,t,u,v,w,x,y,z}';
```

So when I want get `chars[10]` it will return `A`. How to do this in MySQL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the questoin is not about arrays, it is about get random char, right? In this case You can use next approach in MySQL:

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(
        '0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz', 
        ROUND(RAND()*61)+1,
         1
    ) as random_char;
```

The [SUBSTRING](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_substring) function returns one char from random position.

Try it on [SQLize.online](https://sqlize.online/?phpses=null&sqlses=56ed3030678faf8e3af2115ab13fe189&php_version=null&sql_version=mysql57)

Comment: nice and clean. is SUBSTRING more faster than JSON?

Answer (score 1):

Starting MySQL 5.7, one option is to use a JSON array:

```
set @chars = '["0", "1", "A", "B"]';
select json_unquote(json_extract(@chars, '$[2]')) as value_at_index_2;
```

Yields:

```
| value_at_index_2 |
| :--------------- |
| A                |
```

Comment: Your answer is nice too. It's more similiar to approach what postgresql does. but I don't want adding double quote each character. If I still use your answer, can we just remove double quote?